# Method of mocked object returns null after interface downcast

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I am trying to write tests for Spring boot application.
There are two interfaces `INotifier`, and `IMonospaceNotifier` which extends `INotifier` in the application.

```java
public interface INotifier {
    void send(String message);
}

public interface IMonospaceNotifier extends INotifier {
  String monospace(String message);
}
```

Class `TelegramNotifier` implements `IMonospaceNotifier`

````java
@Component
public class TelegramNotifier implements IMonospaceNotifier {
  //Some code omitted
  public void send(String message) {
    //Implementation omitted
  }

  @Override
  public String monospace(String message) {
    return "```\n" + message + "\n```";
  }
}
````

Class `Report` has field of type `INotifier` but in some cases, it is downcasted to `IMonospaceNotifier`

```java
@Component
public class Report {
  //Some code is omitted

  private INotifier notifier;
  @Autowired
  public Report(/*params are omitted*/) {
    // Some code is omitted
    if (reportGenerator.requireMonospace() && !(notifier instanceof IMonospaceNotifier)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("If reportGenerator requests monospace method" +
          " then notifier should be IMonospaceNotifier");
    }
  }

  @Scheduled(cron = "${reportSchedule}")
  public void sendReport() {
    // Some code is omitted
    String report = reportGenerator.generate(workerList);
      if (reportGenerator.requireMonospace()) {
        if (notifier instanceof IMonospaceNotifier) {

          /**
          * This is the problem part. It works fine with normal obejcts 
          * but method `monospace` returns null with mocked objects.
          * I debugged it this codeline is definitely executed and 
          * `report` is not `null` before the execution of this line
          */
          report = ((IMonospaceNotifier) notifier).monospace(report);

        } else {
          assert true : "Should never happen, checked in constructor";
        }
      }
      notifier.send(report);
  }
```

It all works fine until `IMonospaceNotifier` is mocked. With mocked version
`IMonospaceNotifier.monospace()` returns `null` (Please see comment in the code above). Mocked object seems to have the correct type `IMonospaceNotifier$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$...`

The object is mocked in the next way:

````java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "scheduling.enabled=false")
public class MonitorTest {
  @MockBean
  private IMonospaceNotifier notifier;
  @Test
  public void doNothing(){
    /** `notifier.send` is invoked in another bean constructor.
    *  That's why it is working without actual invocation. */

    // This works fine as it doesn't use Report class and downcast
    verify(notifier).send("Hi!, I'm starting"); 
    // The next invocation is actually null
    verify(notifier).send(matches("```┌───.*Worker Name.*")); 
    verify(notifier).send("I'm shutting down. Good Bye!");
  }
}
````

This is how `INotifier` is invoked in a constructor of `Monitor` bean

```java
@Service
public class Monitor {
  @Autowired
  public Monitor(/*params are omitted*/ INotifier notifier) { 

    // This line works fine as it doesn't invoke `monospace`
    notifier.send("Hi!, I'm starting");

    // In `Report` `send()` is executed with `null` as parameter
    // because `monospace()` was invoked
    report.sendReport();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell your mock to return what you want. In your case it looks like you want to return the same object passed in as parameter:

```
public class MonitorTest {
  @MockBean
  private IMonospaceNotifier notifier;

  @Test
  public void doNothing(){
    doAnswer((invocation)-> invocation.getArguments()[0]).when(notifier).monospace(anyString());
  // ...
```

The better option however is to define an independent "report" to be returned so that you have more control in the test case:

```
public class MonitorTest {
  @MockBean
  private IMonospaceNotifier notifier;

  @Test
  public void doNothing(){
    doReturn(SOME_TEST_REPORT_STRING).when(notifier).monospace(anyString());
  // ...
```

Comment: Timothy, thanks for the answer. I actually wanted to call real method, so I modified your answer to `doCallRealMethod().when(notifier).monospace(anyString());` But it doesn't work probably because `Monitor` bean is initialized before `@Test` method. Could you tell me where I need to move this string? I also tried `@Before`.

Comment: @Anton `notifier` is a *mocked interface*, there is no "real method" to call. Also: calling a *real method* on a dependency will violate the  *independence* of test.

Comment: oh, I understand now, thank you. I'm using your first answer(return argument). But it's still not working. I think that it just should be executed before `Monitor` constructor, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Anton a *constructor* should not do anything else then assigning values to (`final`) properties. Especially it should not call methods on *dependencies*. So the best way is to move that functionality out of the constructor into a method that is explicitly called from outside (and not from the constructor).

Comment: Timothy, you really helped me out, thank you. Now I use custom `Monitor.init()` in `main()` and in `Monitor` tests. `Monitor` is the class that starts all logic of the app and before all started from a constructor.